# Copy to clipboard from table cell

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create copy to clipboard from table cell. The idea is that when user hover on first table column cell with his name, the button will show and he can copy it. Is there any way how to create this hover copy button without creating a button in `<td>` tags.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var copyText = document.getElementById("table-cell");

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="table-cell">Mark <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button></td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Where is the user supposed to click, if not in the table?

Comment: you can make your buttons hidden, and when hovering on a cell, display the button

Comment: Yes, but if i have 50 table cells with names I must create 50 buttons for each name or is there any other way how to create it.

Comment: You don't need an id for the cells, use the button element object to get the text content of it's sibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this .. maybe it will help you..

**copy text by hover from table cell..**

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".table-cell").forEach(function(elm){
elm.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
 e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
  var copyText = e.target.textContent; 
   const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = copyText;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);

 
  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + el.value);
  
});

})
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">Jacob </td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Yes it's fine but user needs to click on button to copy the name.

Comment: you write on question that when you hover then table cell will be copy...

Comment: Yes sorry my bad, the button will show after hovering. I will edit it.

Comment: @Sauce btw replace moueover event by the click event... design  yourself as far as need... maybe main problem are solve

Comment: If you can review my code: Why if I click on button it won't copy the content of td? https://codepen.io/S4UCY/pen/abNpyWB

Answer (score 0):

On my own I can offer such a solution. Because you did not have specific requirements, I leave the solution at my discretion.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var copyText = document.getElementById("table-cell");

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```css
#table-cell {
  position: relative;
}

#table-cell p{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 10px;
   margin: 0;
   top: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: blue;
   transition: .3s;
}

.table tr:hover #table-cell p {
   display: block;
}

.table #table-cell p:hover {
   transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="table-cell">Mark <p onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</p></td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td id="table-cell">Jacob <p onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</p></td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="table-cell">Larry <p onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</p></td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: The main idea is to copy the content after hovering on the first table cell (with first name) in a row.