# How to pick the text inside a cell of a table and copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So i don't think i can be more clrear on the tittle.

My problem is i'm making a google extension to copy the name that it is in the cell of a every row  to clipboard.

I already saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63550272/copy-to-clipboard-from-table-cell) but didn't help.

This is my loop to go by all of the table:

```
while(row=table.rows[r++]){
    var c=0; //start counting columns in row
    while(cell=row.cells[c++]){
        if(r>=2){
            if(c==2){//Cell that contains the name of the item
                let text = cell.innerHTML;

                cell.innerHTML = `<b onclick="${copy2Clipboard(text)}">` + text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my function to copy the name to clipboard

```
function copy2Clipboard(itemName){

    //Put in clipboard
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(itemName.innerHTML);
    
    //if don't return this, it will not appear on page idkwhy
    return `copy2Clipboard(${itemName})`;
}
```

Problem I'm getting the always the value of the last item and not each individual item of the table on the clipboard.

If you got any idea to try to make this, i would like to hear
And thanks in advance :)

Comment: please share a sandbox of your code

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change the way you're providing your function name to `onclick`. It also looks like you're missing quotes around `itemName` in the return value of `copy2Clipboard` which will likely cause problems.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

function copy2Clipboard(itemName) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(itemName);
}

var r = 0;
while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
    var c = 0; //start counting columns in row
    while (cell = row.cells[c++]) {
        if (r >= 2) {
            if (c == 2) { //Cell that contains the name of the item
                let text = cell.innerHTML;
                cell.innerHTML = `<b onclick="copy2Clipboard('${text}')">` + text + "</b>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Problem I'm getting the always the value of the last item and not each individual item of the table on the clipboard.

If you're referring to clipboard values being overwritten that's expected. If you're saying only certain cells are bolded and given that handler, there are constraints in your code (`r >= 2, c == 2`) that limit where this functionality is available.

Comment: Tried your idea, didn't work. When i run it appears this error on browser console     `Uncaught ReferenceError: copy2Clipboard is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick`.                    The constrainst is to only pick a column and ingnore the head of the table. Will try to search if there is a way to not overwrite the clipboard or just make an objetct to store the values and just pass the row number and go gets in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your program was incomprehensible to me.
This sample concatenates all cells and puts them on the clipboard.

```js
    var allText = "";
    var r = 0
    while (row = table.rows[r++]) {
      var c = 0; //start counting columns in row
      while (cell = row.cells[c++]) {
        let text = cell.innerHTML;
        allText += text;
      }
    }

    copy2Clipboard(allText);

    function copy2Clipboard(itemName) {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(itemName);
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking wrong when started to make it. Will try another strategy to try to resolve it.

Comment: @Francisco Borges, You should close this question.